# Let $n$ denote the number chosen uniformly from $\{1,2,3, ... 100\}$ What is the probability that another number drawn from $1,2....n$ is $30$?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ denote the event of randomly choosing a number uniformly from the set $\{1,2,3, ... 100\}$. Let this number be denoted by $n$. Another number $k$ is randomly chosen from the set $\{1,2, ... n\}$. What is the probability that $k$ is $30$?

**Attempt:**

In case of the first event $A$, when the number $n$ chosen turns out to be between $1$ and $29$, the second conditional event cannot occur. The second event can only occur when the number $n$ ranges between $\{30,31, ... 100\}$.

Let us suppose the number $n$ turns out to be $30$. In this case, for the second event, the probability that $k$ is 30 is $\frac{1}{30}$ since we can choose $30$ from $\{1, 2, ... 30\}$ in only one way. Similarly, when $n$ is $31$, the probability that $k$ is 30 is $\frac{1}{30}$ since we can choose $30$ from $\{1, 2, ... 31\}$ in only one way. This reasoning can be extended for all values of $n$ till $100$.

If we were to visualize this as a tree, the edges along the first level of the tree would denote the choice of $n$ and the edges along the second level of the tree would denote the choice of $k$. Thus, going by the favorable cases, the probability should be $\frac{1}{100} \times \frac{1}{30}$ for the edges of the tree when $n$ is $30$ and $k$ is $30$. Similarly it should be $\frac{1}{100} \times \frac{1}{31}$ for the edges of the tree when $n$ is $31$ and $k$ is $30$. If we add all of them, we should get the total probability.

Comment: Yes. And where is your question now?

Comment: I did not know whether my attempt was correct or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see that:

If $n=1$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=0$

If $n=2$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=0$

$\qquad\vdots$

If $n=29$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=0$

If $n=30$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=\frac 1{30}$

If $n=31$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=\frac{1}{31}$

$\qquad\vdots$

If $n=100$ then $P(\text{choosing $30$ from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$})=\frac{1}{100}$

Each $n$ has a probability of $\frac 1{100}$ of being chosen, so, we have \begin{align}P(k=30) &= \frac1{100}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{29}0+\sum_{n=30}^{100}\frac 1n\right)\\
&=\frac 1{100}\sum_{n=30}^{100}\frac 1n\\
&\approx 0.0122572\end{align}